# Many2many field with repetition of the same record

Tags: python, xml, many-to-many, odoo, odoo-12

I have a field in my custom model:

```py
class custom_equipment_spec_soft(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom_maintenance.equipment.spec.soft'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
```

And I referenced it inside existing model like this:

```py
soft_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='custom_maintenance.equipment.spec.soft', relation='custom_maintenance_equipment_spec_soft_eq_rel', string='Software')
```

Then I added a view with a tree (table):

```xml
<group>
    <field name="soft_ids" widget="many2many">
        <tree>
            <field name="name"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</group>
```

But now when I pick one record from the database inside the table I can not pick it for the second time. I would like to be able to pick the same record multiple times.

How do I do this? Is this the matter of changing the view widget or it has something to to do this a backend restriction?

Comment: it's the default behavior of many2many field, I think you have to change your DB schema structure to achieve your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create another model with `Many2one` relation to `custom_maintenance.equipment.spec.soft` model let's say `spec.soft.line` and add `One2many` relation to `spec.soft.line` from the existing model, in that case you can have same `custom_maintenance.equipment.spec.soft` record added multiple time.

```
class SpecSoftLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'spec.soft.line'

    spec_soft_id = fields.Many2one('custom_maintenance.equipment.spec.soft')
    existing_model_id = fields.Many2one('existing.model.name')

##Existing model
soft_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='spec.soft.line', inverse_name='existing_model_id')

##On existing model view add
<group>
    <field name="soft_ids" >
        <tree editable="bottom">
            <field name="spec_soft_id"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</group>
```

Comment: Clever idea. But how do I call my fields inside the views? I get an error `Field 'name' does not exist.` I tried to add `spec_soft_id.name` but it does not help.

Comment: Please give <field name="spec_soft_id"/>

Comment: @AnithaDasB but field `spec_soft_id` is defined inside this additional custom model `spec.soft.line` while view is defined on `maintenance.equipment`. And I get error as expected: `Field 'spec_soft_id' does not exist`

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to display other columns (fields) from the orignal model (rather than only a name)? In the example I've had only name field for the sake of simplicity but eventually I want couple more fields in there.